# css - Aligning images in a straight line

Tags: html, css, position

I have 5 images and a div on my webpage. When I load my page the images come one under another but what I want to do is that the images should come in a straight line and the div should show only one at a time.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>My City Karachi</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<div class="slider">
    <img src="asd.jpg"/>
    <img src="baba dedo.jpg"/>
    <img src="picccccture 3.jpg"/>
    <img src="Page-3.jpg"/>
    <img src="Page 4 copy.jpg" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
@charset "utf-8";

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider img {
    width: 900px;
    height: 650px;  
    float:left;
}
```

I hope I was clear enough!

**Any help would be highly appreciated! :)**

Comment: by straight line you meant horizontal line? and your div should show just one image that means other should be display:none? so if only one image is going to appear anyway, what's with the line then?

Comment: Yes @ManishMishra, by straight I mean horizontal but in the future I will make a slider so I can't "display:none" the images.

Comment: If you know the size ofthe images, set the images to position:relative; display:inline; then set your div to same width of the images and overflow:hidden

when you slide the images you can move them with left:-sizeofimage px;

Comment: Areeb, images in HTML display horizontally by default. I am not sure exactly why they don't do that in your particular case, but try to disable styling and make sure they do not overflow the container width, because images also "wrap".

Comment: @lesus Sonession, can you answer that solution to me? I didn't understood what you said! :)

Comment: @amn, that's the problem, I wan't to overflow the container width with the images coming in an horizontal line!

Comment: Than you want an horizontal scrollbar for now with 5 images in it but without changing to the container of the container?

Comment: see, you have 5 images, each with a width of 900px. so obviously, you have more width then the 100%. hence, your float:left cannot show all your divs into horizontal line. anyways, thats not a problem. you will need javascript to make a slider

Comment: @FelipeAls, yes I want 5 images in a horizontal line but without the scrollbar and I without changing the width of ".slider" div.

Comment: The scrollbar will disappear when you remove 4 of the images. That's a script you have to write, I even included a link in my answer to a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
.slider {
 display: block;
}
```

then add display:inline-block; to .slider img

remove float: left;

try that. 
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.slider img {
    width: 900px;
    height: 650px;
    display: inline-block:
}
```

Comment: What size is the slider and what size are the images? For this solution there must be enough vertical space.

Comment: OP: How didn't it work? Like 2 images in a row and 3 others in a second row? Still 1 per row?

Comment: size of slider is 950px x 650px and size of the image is the same!

Comment: Then it won't work :( there must be enough space for the images fit (5*900=4500px)

Comment: see this website : [link](http://www.simpleblog.comlu.com) the slider there have a div if the size of one image and the images are coming from the right, the width of the div is not changed and the images are also in a line!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show your Images in horizontal line

make sure this:

```
width(parent container of Imgs) >= Sum(Width(individual Imgs))
```

only then they will appear in a horizontal line, otherwise they won't.

In your case it won't.

now, since you anyway want to display just one image at a time, then make all of them `display:none` and then just choose one of them (in a given order) and make its `display:block`.

now, since you cannot do it so, using CSS alone, you will need javascript(jQuery).

see this super simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBm57/), demonstrating what you need.

all I am doing is:

- Making all the imgs inside `div.slider` hidden

  ```
   $('.slider img').each(function(i,v){
      $(this).attr("data-image-index",i).hide();
   });
  ```

  also am attaching a new attribute to  your imgs to determine the index i.e.

  ```
  <img src="asd.jpg" alt="img1" data-image-index="0"  />
  <img src="baba dedo.jpg" alt="img2" data-image-index="1" />
   ..
   ..
  ```

  - After then I've made a function, which simply makes all the `div.slider` imgs hidden, and makes the img with `data-image-index` attribute equal to `index` visible.

    ```
       var index=0;
       function play(){
           $('.slider img').each(function(){
                  var s = $(this).data("image-index");
                  if(parseInt(s)===index)
                    $(this).show();
                  else
                    $(this).hide();
            });
            index++;
            if(index>5)
               index=0;
       }
    ```

  now, since we need to call this function play upon click of a button or on a given time interval, I've done this to call it every 1s:

  ```
      setInterval("play()",1000);
  ```

Comment: well, I am a new to Javascript! explain your fiddle please! :)

Comment: explained.and m using jQuery

Comment: if the attr name was "data-image-index" then when you wrote "image-index" only?

Comment: and i accessed it like this :`.data("image-index");` and not `.attr("image-index");`. attributes starting with data- can be accessed like that in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/tceb2/**

A container of fixed width being `overflow: auto` with a child having a width the total width of your 5 images. This will create an horizontal scrollbar.

Then with a script you can create a slideshow by managing which image is shown and which are hidden. Though you will want a width of 350px, not 400px anymore - the width of a single image. Be sure to include controls like Next and Pause/Play, maybe Previous. Far better if it doesn't launch automatically. [Nice tutorial](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html)

Comment: Then I really don't understand what you want. Except if you also want the script written for you and then SO isn't the place you should ask

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui May be you should say why this is not what you want, and what you really want.

Answer (score -2):

Make a ul or ol and add the child items, here images, as li of the same list. in css make sure to have  list-style:none and add margin or padding even position them as needded.